# How to pass a string value argument in VBS User-defined funtions when the user clicks a button (HTA Application)

Tags: vbscript, hta

So, I'm trying to make a program where I can define a program in a button and run it. In this code block (Shown below), I wrote the function but when I start the program, I get this error:

`Line 19, Char 31: Cannot use parenthesis when calling a sub`

I'm not trying to make a subroututine, but a User-defined function. How can I fix this?

Code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Program Launcher</title>
        <script language="VBScript">
            set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

            Function something(Prog, waitProcess)
                objShell.Run Prog, 0, waitProcess
            End Function
        </script> 
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="Test">
            ThisIsATest
        </p>
        <button onclick="something('notepad.exe')">TestObject</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error you get when running this code is:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'something'

To fix this you just need to adjust the `onclick` event handler to match the `something(Prog, waitProcess)` function signature.

The next problem is event handlers are Sub Procedures not Functions so regardless of whether you use a Function or not when assigned to an event handler it treats it as a Sub Procedure, which is why the next issue is;

> Cannot use parenthesis when calling a sub

To fix this you can either;

1. Drop the brackets

   ```
   onclick="something 'notepad.exe', True"
   ```
2. Use `Call`

   ```
   onclick="Call something('notepad.exe', True)"
   ```

Here is an example that uses `Call` and a `MsgBox()` to output the values passed to the event handler.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <HTA:APPLICATION ID="Test" 
            BORDER="thick" 
            BORDERSTYLE="complex"/>
        <title>Program Launcher</title>
        <style>

        </style>
        <script language="VBScript">
            Sub something(Prog, waitProcess)
                MsgBox("Triggered: " & Prog & ", " & waitProcess)
                Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                Call objShell.Run("cmd /c " & Prog, 0, waitProcess)
            End Sub
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="Test">
            ThisIsATest
        </p>
        <button onclick="Call something('notepad.exe', True)">TestObject</button> 
    </body>
</html>
```